# Google Table Merge columns

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a page that displays data in the form of a Table. I use Google Charts and here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["table"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Task', 'Hours per Day', 'Test', 'Hours per Day', 'Test'],
          ['Work',     11, 12, 11, 12],
          ['Eat',      2, 13, 2, 13],
          ['Commute',  2, 15, 2, 34],
          ['Watch TV', 2, 17, 7, 24],
          ['Sleep',    7, 18, 2, 13]
        ]);

       var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('tablechart'));
       chart.draw(data);
      }
    </script>
<div id="tablechart" style="width: 700px; height: 400px; position: relative;"></div>
```

And here's a working JS FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/alex4uthis/kt21bf0k/

I would like to get the following format:
[image]

(I would like to merge Jan and Feb same as in the image)
Please advise...

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do that with the Google Charts API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `'ready'` event to change the chart manually once finished drawing.

There are no options available in the google chart to add additional header rows.
Which makes this answer somewhat of a hack.

Regardless, the chart itself is a normal `TABLE` element

This is a simple example and I make assumptions based on the data provided to the chart.
Other factors may need to be considered as well.
For instance, when a scrollbar is present and the header row remains fixed, there will be a second header row to deal with. Last I checked anyway...

This approach should work fine given a simple table chart.
I have used this approach to add total rows at the bottom, etc...

I use `cloneNode` to make sure the new row has the same style as the rest of the chart.

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table'], callback: drawChart});

function drawChart() {
  var divTableChart;

  divTableChart = document.getElementById('tablechart');

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day', 'Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work',     11, 'Work', 12],
    ['Eat',      2, 'Work', 13],
    ['Commute',  2, 'Work', 34],
    ['Watch TV', 2, 'Work', 24],
    ['Sleep',    7, 'Work', 13]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(divTableChart);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var headerRow;
    var newRow;

    // get header row and clone to keep google chart style
    headerRow = divTableChart.getElementsByTagName('THEAD')[0].rows[0];
    newRow = headerRow.cloneNode(true);

    // modify new row to combine cells and add labels
    newRow.deleteCell(newRow.cells.length - 1);
    newRow.deleteCell(newRow.cells.length - 1);
    newRow.cells[0].colSpan = 2;
    newRow.cells[0].innerHTML = 'Jan';
    newRow.cells[1].colSpan = 2;
    newRow.cells[1].innerHTML = 'Feb';

    // insert new / cloned row
    divTableChart.getElementsByTagName('THEAD')[0].insertBefore(newRow, headerRow);
  });

  chart.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="tablechart"></div>
```